# Randomly take an int element from an integer array

Tags: java, arrays, return

I have an Integer array and I want to randomly take an element from those who are not null. I have tried this but after the else, I cannot use return because the method is `int`. But I don't know what to write after else in order to return at the beginning and take a new random element.

```
public int getRandomPosition(){
    Random x = new Random();
    int b = x.nextInt(2*number0fCardPairs);
    if (myArray[b] != null){
       return b;
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your array size is 2*numberOfCardPairs?

Comment: Could you please provide the code you have so far? I didn't got why you can't use return.

Comment: You need to return an int in your last return statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your method recursive:

```java
private Random x = new Random();

public int getRandomPosition(){
    int b = x.nextInt(sizeOfArray);
    if (myArray[b] != null){
       return b;
    }
    // else {
    return getRandomPosition();
}
```

or using a while-loop

```java
private Random x = new Random();

public int getRandomPosition(){
    Integer result = null; 
    do {
      int index = x.nextInt(sizeOfArray);
      result = myArray[index];
    } while (result == null);
    return result.intValue();
}
```

**Theoretically**, however, the method could run indefinitely if you're really unlucky. Therefore, it probably makes sense to include a counter, so for example only try max. 20 times, then return `null`:

```java
private Random x = new Random();

public int getRandomPosition(){
    Integer result = null; 
    int tries = 0;
    do {
      int index = x.nextInt(sizeOfArray);
      result = myArray[index];
    } while (result == null && ++tries < 20);
    return result.intValue();
}
```

Comment: Nice. Note that there is a chance that the recursive method will result in `StackOverFlowException` since it might call itself many times depending on how many nulls are in the array and coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a loop.

```
public int getRandomPosition(){
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomIdx = random.nextInt(array.length);

    // while array at randomIdx is null, continue getting new randomIdx
    while (array[randomIdx] == null) {
        randomIdx = random.nextInt(array.length);
    }

    return randomIdx;
}
```

Note that if all the elements inside the array are null, it will be an infinite loop. Hope you find this helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
Integer[] myArray = {1,2,3,null,5};

List<Integer> nonNullIntegers = Arrays.stream(myArray)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

Random random = new Random();
Integer randomInteger = nonNullIntegers.get(random.nextInt(nonNullIntegers.size()));
```